# why is my application throwing finalizer exception in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have an application in which there is constantly this exception being thrown...

```
04-25 18:47:38.024: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.035: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44dd1e68 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.035: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.035: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 18:47:38.044: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.064: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44e4c048 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.064: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.064: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 18:47:38.074: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.094: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44e35310 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.094: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.094: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 18:47:38.104: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.104: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44e7f738 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.104: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.104: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 18:47:38.114: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.136: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44e04a90 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.136: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.136: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 18:47:38.155: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.155: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44e944f0 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.155: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.155: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 18:47:38.164: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.184: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44e90548 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.184: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.184: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 18:47:38.194: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.194: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44e6b0c8 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.194: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.194: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
04-25 18:47:38.204: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
04-25 18:47:38.225: INFO/dalvikvm(10290): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44e4af40 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
04-25 18:47:38.237: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
04-25 18:47:38.245: INFO/dalvikvm(10290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

i don't understand why this is happening. i have closed all my cursors, and also i have closed the cursors before the databases...
ie `c.close()` comes before `db.close()`

what could be the problem?

thank you in advance.

EDIT:
i think this class is causing the exception because it is the only one dealing with databases

```
package com.helios.NauticDates;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class HandleDatabase {

    public void executeSql(String query) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                "/data/data/com.helios.NauticDates/CalendarEvent.sqlitedb",
                null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    }

    public boolean checkCategory(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                "/data/data/com.helios.NauticDates/CalendarEvent.sqlitedb",
                null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String query = "select * from EventCategories where categoryname ='"
                + name + "'";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            c.close();
            db.close();
            return true;
        } else {
            c.close();
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String[][] getData(String[] columnnames, String tablename) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                "/data/data/com.helios.NauticDates/CalendarEvent.sqlitedb",
                null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String query = "select ";
        for (int i = 0; i < columnnames.length; i++) {
            if (i == columnnames.length - 1)
                query += columnnames[i] + " ";
            else
                query += columnnames[i] + ",";
        }
        query += "from " + tablename + " where eventid=128";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        String[][] result = new String[c.getColumnCount()][c.getCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            for (int j = 0; j < c.getCount(); j++) {
                result[i][j] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columnnames[i]));
                Log.i("getdata", result[i][j]);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    public boolean checkIfThereIsEvent(String cdate, Date currentdate) {
        Date enddate = (Date) currentdate.clone();
        enddate.setHours(0);
        enddate.setMinutes(0);
        enddate.setSeconds(0);
        String edate = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format(
                "yyyy-MM-dd", enddate);

        Log.i("handledatabase", cdate + "-" + edate);
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                "/data/data/com.helios.NauticDates/CalendarEvent.sqlitedb",
                null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String query = "SELECT datetime(startdat, 'unixepoch') AS std, datetime(enddat, 'unixepoch') AS end FROM EventDetails WHERE ((std <= '"
                + cdate
                + "' AND end >= '"
                + cdate
                + "' )||( date(enddat,'unixepoch') = '1970-01-01' AND date(startdat,'unixepoch') = '"
                + edate + "')) LIMIT 1";
        Log.i("thequery", query);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            c.close();
            db.close();
            return true;
        }
        {
            c.close();
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkEventInDatabase(String dateofchange, String eventid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                "/data/data/com.helios.NauticDates/CalendarEvent.sqlitedb",
                null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String query = "select * from EventDetails where eventid='"+eventid+"' limit 1";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(c.getCount()==0){
            c.close();
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            query = "select * from EventDetails where eventid='"+eventid+"'and changed='"+dateofchange+"' limit 1";
            c= db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if(c.getCount()>0){
                c.close();
                db.close();
                return true;
            }
            else{
                c.close();
                db.close();
                return true;
            }
    }
}

    public boolean checkIfEventChanged(String dateofchange, String eventid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                "/data/data/com.helios.NauticDates/CalendarEvent.sqlitedb",
                null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String query = "select * from EventDetails where eventid='"+eventid+"'and changed='"+dateofchange+"' limit 1";
        Cursor c= db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(c.getCount()>0){
            c.close();
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            c.close();
            db.close();
            return true; 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: can't tell you any more than what the error message says without seeing some code.

Comment: usually when is this exception thrown...?

Comment: show us the complete error please, not just the first 3 lines...

Comment: that is the complete error, this same error keeps on repeating over and over again...

Comment: under what condition you r getting this exeception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `else` towards the end of `checkIfThereIsEvent()`.

If that does not clear it up, simply log each `Cursor` you open yourself via a call to `Log`, and then compare the log entries to figure out which `Cursor` is the one being leaked.

Also:

- Never hardwire paths. Get rid of `/data/data/com.helios.NauticDates`. Either use `SQLiteOpenHelper` or use `getDatabasePath()`.
- There is no value in continuously opening and closing your database this way. Please consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, putting these methods on that class, and keeping your `SQLiteOpenHelper` around longer (e.g., lifetime of your activity or service, or a singleton for your whole app)

Comment: The else is not important there, because the if contains a return, so when the if statement is true, the method never execute the block which should be the else part

Comment: @WarrenFaith: Yeah, I kinda assumed it'd be OK, but I wanted to point it out just in case.

Answer (score 2):

An addition to CommonsWare:

In your `checkEventInDatabase()` you reassign the `c` variable, if the `c.getCount()` is not 0, so there you create an cursor which you never close.

And please: Every time you call `getCount()` or `getColumnCount()` in a loop, god kills a kitten! (see `getData()`)